# Android studio IDE font changed

Tags: android-studio

I have encountered bizarre problem with IDE's font.
Currently my IDE looks this

[image: My IDE at the moment]

Normally it should look this

[image: Default IDE font]

What I did which may affect font - recently have been adding Japanese language as secondary keyboard layout and while I was in IDE switched to Japanese and started typing.
What I have tried - deleting config folder.

My settings:

[image: Settings]

Thanks.

Comment: @ModularSynth indeed, it is an exact tab in the preferences. Obviously, as all settings are set to default, font should be the same as on the screenshot 2. And obviously I have tried using different fonts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to fix this. Even if settings are default, you have to manually change font and size in IDE. 
If anyone has the same problem:

1. Make a copy of your theme
2. Set font to Consolas with size 15